# How to access "The grimm Troupe" and "Hidden dreams" content in Hollow Knight?

Tags: hollow-knight

In these two official announcements from Team Cherry, it's said:

https://steamcommunity.com/games/367520/announcements/detail/3121414788974528116

> Grimm’s quest, and all other new features **can be accessed at any point
>   in your Hollow Knight journey**.

https://steamcommunity.com/games/367520/announcements/detail/1327847269945274512

> Hollow Knight: Hidden Dreams content is accessible **at any point in the
>   game**, whether starting fresh or scouring for completion.

I still haven't find any way to start the quests from the menus or during beginning of the game. Some sources say the content can only be accessed late in the game from specific locations.

So, is Team Cherry simply lying in our faces?

Comment: I think what they mean is that you can't get to a point where you've already locked yourself out of that content and can't access it any more. Both content updates mostly added late game content, so you might not be at the point yet where you can find that content. At this point you also won't notice whether any content was added as part of those updates or not, they integrate into the game seamlessly.

Comment: Pitty. I spent 36 hours to finish the game and don't want to spend another 20 hours just to get to the point where I can access the extra content, that is probably very small.

Comment: at 36 hours you've probably already seen some of the new content. There's at least 4 bosses, 3 charms and a dream nail ability that were added. And at the point where you've finished the game, most of this content should at least be accessible.

Comment: I played this before the first DLC was released. I already deleted the save data. I need to restart the game and play a lot of it just to see little content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the additional content immediately appears at the places on the map where it can be accessed. However, it is useful to know where to find them if already have explored a lot and don't want to backtrack.

### Grimm Troupe

Apart from the minor improvements (e.g. charms), the major part of the Grimm Troupe update is available after 'summoning the troupe' at a small cave accessible from the large cliff on the west of the Howling Cliffs. After that that, the Grimm Troupe appears in Dirtmouth.

### Hidden Dreams

The Hidden Dreams content doesn't really have a quest like the Grimm Troupe, but a noticeable piece of content is the Dreamgate (unlocked after gathering enough Essence) and some two bosses in dreams that are *hidden*:

1:

> "Grey prince Zote". Found in Bretta's house. Unlocked after both saving Bretta and defeating Zote in the colosseum. This of course requires you to *not* let Zote die when you encounter him, so this is the only part on which you *could* miss out in your current play-through.

2:

> "White defender". Found in a hidden room near the Dung Defender. Unlocked after defeating the Dung Defender and all three Dreamers.